# How to change step pulses into PWM pulse synchronously?

Tags: microcontroller, motor, stepper-motor, dsp, stepper-driver

I am driving a stepper motor using microstepping techniques.
For the input signals to the driver, step and dir are used.
More than 100,000 steps/second speed is target.
The PWM frequency is below 100KHz. How to convert the step pulses into PWM pulses synchronously ? I want the rate should be same even though the constant buffer delay exists.
At this moment, ISR routine for step pin handles counting up/down pulse.

But when i mill something for test on my CNC with my stepper drive, the 3D output quality isn't pretty good compared to with other vendors high performance closed loop stepper.

So i guess there is an input jitter on step pulses.

Comment: "i guess there is an input jitter on step pulses", do you have anything to measure this with?

Comment: How are you generating the PWM, and what is it driving?

Comment: I have checked input pulses applying into other vendors drive. It works correctly compared to my drive. My logic to change step pulses to PWM pulses isn't complete i think. I wonder if there is better algorithm